# How to show that $y'(x)=y(x+1)$ is not an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An ODE is an equation of the form $F(x,y(x),y'(x),\dotsc,y^{(n)}(x))=0$, where $F$ is a real-valued function defined on some subset of $\mathbb R^{n+2}$.

Now, given this definition, how can I show that $y'(x)=y(x+1)$ is *not* an ODE? What this means has not been explicitly defined in our course, but I think it means that there is no $F$ such that the equation $F(x,y(x),y'(x),\dotsc,y^{(n)})=0$ has exactly the same solutions as $y'(x)=y(x+1)$.

The model solution to the problem just states that the equation is not an ODE, so I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious. Of course it *seems* that it should not be since the equation depends on the value $y(x+1)$ whereas $F$ is only given $y(x)$. But a little voice in my head says that maybe it could be possible to deduce $y(x+1)$ from $y(x)$ or something so that in principle such $F$ *could* exist.

Comment: If it were an ODE, then you would be able to represent $y^{(n)}(0)$ as a function only of $y(0),y'(0),\dots,y^{(n-1)}(0)$. But this is impossible. For a concrete example, consider $y \equiv 0$ and $z = x^n$. Both of these have all of the first $n-1$ derivatives zero at 0, but they differ at $x=1$, so if the delay equation were an ODE, we would have an ambiguity in the choice of $y^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: This doesn't directly address your question, but may be nonetheless of interest to you: If the equation were $y'(x)=y(x-1)$ it would be an instance of a delay differential equation (DDE), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation.

Comment: @Ian: I'm not sure I follow. It seems that you're assuming that every ODE can be expressed in the form $y^{(n)}=f(x,y,y',\dotsc,y^{(n-1)})$, but AFAIK that's not the case. It also seems that even then, the example $z=x^n$ doesn't help because it's not a solution to the given DDE?

Comment: For a solution which has the appropriate smoothness to exist, given fixed values $x,y_0,y'_0,\dots,y^{(n-1)}_0$, the equation $F(x,y_0,\dots,y^{(n)})=0$ should have a unique solution for $y^{(n)}$. Otherwise there is an ambiguity in the choice of the nth derivative at $x$ which means that $y^{(n)}(x)$ does not truly exist at all.

Comment: @Ian: I'm not very good at analysis, so you have to be more specific. Are you referring to the implicit function theorem? In our definition of ODE, nothing extra is assumed about $F$; it's just a partial function on $\mathbb R^{n+2}$.

Comment: The ODE doesn't make sense if $y^{(n)}$ can't be uniquely specified for each $x$, since otherwise it isn't a derivative of any function. The implicit function theorem gives sufficient conditions on $F$ for the ODE to make sense. Basically, $F$ should be invertible with respect to any of its arguments except possibly the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to write $y(x + 1)$ as a function of the independent variables $x, y(x), y'(x), \ldots, y^{(n)}(x)$ of the function $F$ for any $n$. In principle one can see this by showing that for any choice of respective values $x_0, y_0, y_1, \ldots, y_n$ there are functions $f$ and $g$ such that $$f^{(k)}(x_0) = g^{(k)}(x_0), \qquad k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$$ but $$f(x_0 + 1) \neq g(x_0 + 1).$$

Comment: To use this I guess I would have to find $f$ and $g$ like this which are solutions to the DDE. Then both would be solutions to the proposed ODE $F(x,y(x),\dotsc,y^{(n)}(x))=0$ with the same initial conditions at $x_0$, so $f=g$..? But I don't even have any idea how to prove the existence of these $f$ and $g$. Or is there another way?

Comment: @nonpop Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n y_i (x-x_0)^i$ and let $g(x)=(x-x_0)^{n+1} + \sum_{i=0}^n y_i (x-x_0)^i$. These both have all the specified derivatives at $x_0$ but they differ at $x_0+1$. You can generate variants on this example using Hermite interpolation. Without being able to generate an example, however, you should expect this sort of thing to happen: if it didn't, then a function would be uniquely determined by its nth degree Taylor polynomial, which would mean every n-times differentiable function would have to be a polynomial!

Comment: Can you show how to exactly use these to answer the question in the title? Because I still don't see it :p I do now see how $y(x+1)$ is not determined by $x,y(x),\dotsc,y^{(n)}(x)$ but that's not the whole story, is it.

Comment: The point is, that *is* the whole story: Two functions can have the same $0$th through $n$th derivatives at a point $x_0$ but different values at $x_0 + 1$, and therefore those derivatives at $x_0$ don't determine the value of either function at $x_0 + 1$; hence, $y(x + 1)$ is not a function of $x_0$ and those derivatives.